# jQuery Mobile code producing more and more lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dialog

Hello there overflowers,

I have some strage error in my jQuery Mobile code and I can't figure out what the problem is.

Here is the code

```
.on("pageshow", "#dlg1", function(){
    $("#buttonAdd")
    .on("click", function(){
        var n = $("input[id^=modDescription]").length;
        var addThis = "";
        addThis = '<tr class="modRow"><td><input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="modDescription' + n + '" id="modDescription' + n + '" value=""></td>';
        addThis += '<td><input type="number" name="modValue' + n + '" id="modValue' + n + '" value=""></td><td><button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext" id="modDelete' + n + '"></button></td></tr>';
        $("#tabDialog > tbody").append(addThis).trigger("create");
    })
})
```

Some explenation: I have a page with various buttons. All the buttons open the same dialog "dlg1", when pressed. Inside the dialog I have a number of text input fields in table rows, each having a id+counter with the same html structure as inside the addThis-Variable. At the end there is a add Button which should create a new row inside the table.

Now here is a testcase:

- Press a button to open dialog -> dialog opens
- Press add button -> new line is generated -> OK!

Here is another testcase:

- Press a button to open dialog -> dialog opens
- Press add button -> new line is generated
- Close dialog -> dialog closes, I'm back at the main page
- Press a button to open dialog -> dialog opens
- Press add button -> TWO lines are generated! -> NOT OK!

The more often I change between page and dialog, the more lines are generated with the add buttons.

Why is that so? What am I doing wrong? How can I fix this? I can provide more Information (code) if needed.

Thanks in advance for your replies.
r-kane with his first question here

Comment: My guess is that "pageshow" event is triggered when you think its not happening. Add a console.log inside the function and see when it is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this case, but i guess that "pageshow" is triggered more then once. 
Try adding

```
$("#buttonAdd").unbind("click")
```

Before

```
$("#buttonAdd").on("click"...
```

**unbind** tells jquery to forget all events of the argumented type to that element.

Comment: This helped me a step further! Thanks! Now I unbind the click of pagehide and when I reopen the dialog, then it produces only one new line as expected :)

Answer (score 0):

I think its because you add an .on('click', ...) event at **#buttonAdd** EVERY time the dialog is shown .on('pageshow' ...)

So the second time you open (show) the dialog, 2 on click event are attached to **#buttonAdd** and 2 on click event are triggered when you click it.

Try to remove the .on('pageshow' ...) or replace it with:

```
$("#dlg1").on("click", "#buttonAdd", function(){
        var n = $("input[id^=modDescription]").length;
        var addThis = "";
        addThis = '<tr class="modRow"><td><input type="text" data-clear-btn="true" name="modDescription' + n + '" id="modDescription' + n + '" value=""></td>';
        addThis += '<td><input type="number" name="modValue' + n + '" id="modValue' + n + '" value=""></td><td><button class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-notext" id="modDelete' + n + '"></button></td></tr>';
        $("#tabDialog > tbody").append(addThis).trigger("create");
    });
```

Comment: I tried this and inserted a console.log output, but it seems that the function is never triggered - I don't get any response in the console.